# Pullback of constant sheaf of abelian groups is isomorphic to another constant sheaf

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification, sheaf-theory

This is all coming from Example 8 in Lecture 2 of [Pramod Achar's lecture notes on perverse sheaves](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Epramod/tc/ps/psln.pdf).

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous map of any two *arbitrary topological spaces*, and let $A$ be any abelian group.
In general, for $\mathcal F$ a sheaf on $Y$, the pull-back $f^{-1}\mathcal F$ is defined to be the sheafification of the presheaf $\text{ps} f^{-1} \mathcal F$, where for $U \subset X$ open, $$ \text{ps} f^{-1} \mathcal F(U) = \{ \text{equivalence classes of pairs }(V,s)\text{ where }V \supset f(U) \text{ and } s \in \mathcal F (V) \},$$
where the equivalence relation is the same as that for stalks.

The constant sheaf $\underline{A}_X$ is defined by $\underline{A}_X(U) = \{\text{locally constant } g: U \to A\}$ for $U \subset X$ open, and a similar definition for $\underline{A}_Y$.
I want to show the following:

> There is an isomorphism of sheaves, $f^{-1} \underline{A}_Y \cong \underline{A}_X$.

Since the stalks of a presheaf and its sheafification are isomorphic, I know that to show the above statement **it suffices to show that the stalks of $\underline{A}_X$ and $\text{ps} f^{-1} \underline{A}_Y$ are isomorphic,** where the stalks are given by $$(\underline{A}_X)_p = \{[U,s] : p \in U, s: U \to A \text{ locally constant}\}$$ and $$(\text{ps} f^{-1} \underline{A}_Y)_p = \{[U, [V,t]] : Y \supset V \supset f(U), U \ni p, t: V \to A \text{ locally constant}\}.$$

To that end, I want to define a morphism of presheaves $F : \text{ps} f^{-1} \underline{A}_Y \to \underline{A}_X$.
For $U \subset X$ open, $$ \text{ps} f^{-1} \underline{A}_Y (U) = \{ [V,s] : V \supset f(U), s: V \to A \text{ locally constant}\}, $$ and $$ \underline{A}_X(U) = \{g: U \to A \text{ locally constant}\}.$$
Define $F([V,s]) = s \circ f$, which induces a homomorphism $F_p$ on the stalks given by $$F_p[U, [V,t]] = [U, F_U[V,t]] = [U, t \circ f].$$
Then all I need to do is check that this is in fact an isomorphism, which does not seem so hard.

My question is: is the outline I've given above all correct for showing the statement? There are a lot of definitions involved at the very beginning of learning about sheaves, and I want to check that my understanding is correct.
Alternate explanations of the statement would also be helpful - I am familiar with the definition of co/limits and how they relate to the pullback sheaf, but am not so clear on proving things e.g. the above with those definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give an alternate proof which also proves some nice and useful facts about constant sheaves.

**Lemma 1 :** For any space $X$, let $a_X:X\to\{*\}$ be the unique map to the one point set. Then $\underline{A}_X\simeq a_X^{-1}\underline{A}_{\{*\}}$.

Of course, your assertion immediately implies the above lemma. But it is also equivalent. Indeed : let $f:X\to Y$ be any continuous map, then we obviously have $a_Y\circ f=a_X$, so $f^{-1}\underline{A}_Y\simeq f^{-1}a_Y^{-1}\underline{A}_{\{*\}}\simeq (a_Y\circ f)^{-1}\underline{A}_{\{*\}}=a_X^{-1}\underline{A}_{\{*\}}\simeq\underline{A}_X$.

Now, let us prove the lemma 1. By definition $a_X^{-1}\underline{A}_{\{*\}}$ is the sheafification of the presheaf $\operatorname{ps}a_X^{-1}\underline{A}_{\{*\}}$ which is obviously (recall the definition of $\operatorname{ps}a_X^{-1}$) the constant presheaf $U\mapsto A$ with all restriction maps being the identity. To conclude, it suffices to prove :

**Lemma 2** : The constant sheaf $\underline{A}_X$ is the sheafification of the constant presheaf $\underline A^p_X : U\mapsto A$.

To prove this, consider the map $\varphi:\underline A^p_X\to \underline A_X$ such that for any $U\subset X$, $\varphi_U:\underline A^p_X(U)\to \underline A_X(U)$ is the map which sends $a\in \underline A^p_X(U)=A$ to the constant function $f:U\to A$ with value $a$. The lemma 2 is proved if we can show that this induces an isomorphism on stalks. But obviously $(\underline A^p_X)_x=A$ and $(\underline{A}_X)_x$ is also isomorphic to $A$ via the map which send a locally constant function $f$ defined in a neighborhood of $x$ to $f(x)$. And clearly, $\varphi_x$ is the identity with the above identification.